# Evaluating integrals with trigonometric function

Tags: integration, solution-verification

Now I have to evaluate the integrals 
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \sin^2 t \cos t dt $$
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \cos t \sin^2 t dt $$
$$  \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \tan^2 t dt $$

For the first two integrals, I could substitute $u=\sin t$ and $du=\cos tdt$  I get  $$ \int_{0}^{1}  u^2  du = \frac{1}{3} $$

The last one though, I don't quite get it. changing $ \tan^2 t = \sec^2t - 1$ then getting the integral would then result to 
$ \tan t - t$, 
 but $ \tan (\pi/2) - (\pi/2)$ would yields infinity,

so is the final answer of the three integrals $ \frac{1}{3},\; \frac{1}{3}, \;   \infty$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you did everything correct to me, although I must point out that the first two integrals appear to be identical? Unless for one of them you meant $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2(x)\sin(x)\text{d}x$$ As for the integral involving tangent, you are still correct. Getting "$\infty$" in this case means the area under that curve along $[0,\pi/2]$ is infinite, so we have a divergent integral.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\tan^{2}x=\sec^{2}x-1$$
We have to evaluate,
$$\int \sec^{2}x-1dx= \tan x-x+c$$
Through your limits you see that the integral is divergent.